# Rails 4 Include Rails.application.routes.url_helper undefined method routes for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a Ruby gem (aimed at Rails 4) and I want to be able to use the url helpers in it.  So I've tried adding `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`, but it results in "undefined method 'routes' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)."

I am unsure as to why it does this as I've tested in the console and when I included it there it does just fine.

The class and module is simple just:

```
 module DynamicMenu
  class Base
    include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
    def get_menu_links
      @links
    end
    private

    def define_menu_links(args)
     @links = args
    end
  end
end
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?  I've tried including diffent modules, such as ActionView::Helpers, but that doesn't appear to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it, though probably not the best way is to use `included` and `method_missing`.  This is of course assuming that you are in `ActionView` or `ActionController`

Something like this should do OK:

```
module DynamicMenu

   def included(base)
       @parent = base
   end

   def method_missing method, *args
       super unless @parent.methods.index method
       @parent.send(method,args)
   end

 end
```